# elasticsearch scripted fields alongside _source

Tags: elasticsearch

Following [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) about script fields i build a query something like this

```
GET /abc/dfg/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "object.property": {
                    "gte": 6.05,
                    "lte": 18.15,
                    "include_lower": false,
                    "include_upper": false
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "geo_distance": {
                  "distance": "25mi",
                  "object.geo_point_property": {
                    "lat": 40.753333,
                    "lon": -73.976667
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc['object.geo_point_property'].planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat,params.lon, 0)",
        "params": {
          "lat": 40.753333,
          "lon": -73.976667
        },
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i get the distance scripted field on the hits but lost all _source fields from documents.

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "abc",
    "_type": "dfg",
    "_id": "123456789",
    "_score": 5.431662,
    "fields": {
      "distance": [
        452.7564081099714
      ]
    }
  },
]
```

There is any way i can get scripted fields alongside _source fields of the document?

i look for something like:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "abc",
    "_type": "dfg",
    "_id": "123456789",
    "_score": 5.431662,
    "fields": {
      "distance": [
        452.7564081099714
      ]
      "object": {
        "property": 123,
        "geo_point_property": xyz
      }
    }
  },
]
```

PD: im using elastic 5.1

Comment: What happens if you add `"_source": true` at the top level of your query?

Comment: Excellent @Val that did it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `_source: true` to your query

```
POST /abc/dfg/_search
{
  "_source": true,         <--- add this
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
      ...
```